# cannot find symbol new MapsPackage() in MainApplication.java

Tags: javascript, react-native, maps

Im trying to use react-native-maps.

I already `yarn add react-native-maps` and `react-native link`.

`import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage;` is already on `MainApplication.java`

What i am missing?

Edit: Sorry, here is the error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
new MapsPackage()
^
symbol: class MapsPackage
2 errors
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: There's not much info in this question. You should at least include the code that causes the error.

Comment: The code that caused the error, is a blank react-native project, with yarn add react-native-maps and react-native link. The error happens when i try to react-native run-android.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add 
`compile project(':react-native-maps')` in `build.gradle` in app folder.